# How do I access 'img' in this json object? php, laravel-5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

I have this json data: (the result of var_dump($stored_images)

```
{ ["stored_images"]=> string(169)
 "[
   {"img":"image1.jpg"},
   {"img":"img2.jpg"}
 ]" 
}
```

This is how I created the object:

```
var stored_images_obj = []
                $.each($('#works-on-file img'), function(index, value){
                        item = {}
                        item['img'] = (value.currentSrc);
                        stored_images_obj.push(item);
                });
                console.log(stored_images_obj);
             $('#input-stored-images').val(JSON.stringify(stored_images_obj));
```

And I store it in this variable in my controller:

```
$stored_images= Input::only('stored_images');
```

I have a feeling my json format is incorrect but not sure what to do.  I tried other ways to create it but it always ends up the same.

I need to access each 'img' object in the output. How would I do that?

**okay I got it. Thanks Felix king**

I just stored it as one array of string instead, and then did

```
$images = explode(',',$string)
```

now I can access it by doing

```
$images[0]
```

Comment: Why don't you create `["image1.jpg", "img2.jpg"]` instead? Seems unnecessary to have objects with a single key.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I expect he'll have meta data on the images.

Comment: so how would I access my images from this ? `{ ["stored_images"]=> string(147) "image1.jpg,img2.jpg" }`

Comment: No, that JSON is messed up.  Hold on, making an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var images = [];
$('#works-on-file img').each( function(index, value){
    images.push( { 
        src: value.currentSrc
    } );
});
images.forEach( function(img){
    $('#stored-images')
        .append( '<div>' )
        .append( img.src );
})
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/Lu1w9bpp/

This saves a json file like the following:

```
[
    { "src": "image1.jpg" },
    { "src": "image2.jpg" }
]
```

You don't need that other stuff.